# Remove warning when execute asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

THis is my AsycTask

```
class LoadAsync extends
        AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, ArrayList<Float>> {
    private ProgressDialog mPd;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
                     //do something
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Float> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {
                     //do something
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Float> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Float> scAnalysis) {
                     //do something
    }
}
```

And my Activity I execute Asynctask by

```
ArrayList<String> arrInput = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrInput.add("var1");
    arrInput.add("var2");
    arrInput.add("var3");
    new LoadAsync().execute(arrInput);  //here display warning
```

Content of warning: Type safety: A generic array of ArrayList is created for a varargs parameter asynctask execute

I want to remove this warning..How must I do

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
ArrayList<String> arrInput = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrInput.add("var1");
    arrInput.add("var2");
    arrInput.add("var3");
    new LoadAnalysis().execute(arrInput);
```

with

```
new LoadAnalysis().execute("var1", "var2", "var3");
```

and the warning will go away.

Of course you have also to change

```
 AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>
```

with

```
 AsyncTask<String
```

and you can access `"var1", "var2", "var3",` through params as array:

```
params[0] is "var1"
```

and so on. Take a look to the documentation for [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Comment: @anata: If the above answer solves your problem then please consider accepting the answer so that others will know this question got a solution.